# Not actively looking, but got a good job offer

Tags: job-search

I am a software development professional.  I joined a company 6 years ago (Job #1), and worked my way up to a management position within 3.  At that time I wasn't actively looking to make a move, but was offered and accepted a job with another company for more pay and less initial responsibility (with the opportunity to manage the team after proving myself).  I left on good terms and maintained relationship with colleagues, including my former manager there.

The job at the new company (Job #2) did not pan out as expected, as the CEO and I had very different management philosophies, and therefore didn't want to promote me to the team manager.  I decided that I needed to exit in order to get back on track in my career to develop further as a manager.  My former employer made an offer to me to return to my previous management role, which I accepted.

2 years pass - There are some aspects of my job that weren't ideal, but I wasn't dissatisfied to the point of job searching.  I was contacted by a CTO wanting to hire me into a management role, of which I came highly recommended by contacts I had made while at Job #2.  The opportunity would allow me to develop in areas not possible in my current organization, while keeping equal commute, workload (in terms of hours/week), with a ~20% raise in base salary.

The offer is very compelling, but I'm concerned with the following:

1. I do not want to mar my professional reputation or sour relationships with people at my current company.  They thought highly enough of me to offer me my old job back.  After only being back in the role close to 2 years, it seems a bit flaky to leave once more.
2. I am concerned about being perceived further along in my career as a job-hopper.  I join firms with the intention of staying as long as possible, but my resume reflects several short-lived stays.  This includes moving to another city to follow my spouse's new job, and being part of a layoff in a separate instance, but some moves were to get more time at home as my children came into our family.  I know the growing trend in IT is that people are spending less time with a company than years before.

**In your opinion, is leaving for another opportunity (better for career development) a good move, even after just rejoining the company I left not long ago?**

Comment: Why is this question voted down?

Comment: It is completely valid question IMHO. How to handle such situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you rejoined your company two years ago and now you see that you have been in a rut for the last two years, I don't see what you gain by staying in the rut for two more years. Trouble starts for you when you allow your skills set to get out date for whatever reason. Since you are married with children, you can't really afford to let your skills set to get too far out of date.

I think the question you should ask yourself is not "what will others think of me if leave after two years?", it is whether they really need you at your current firm. Since you've been in a rut there for the last two years, I'd guess their need for specifically you to stay is probably not acute and they can most likely get by without your services. In other words, you are not indispensable. In this case, I suggest that you offer your services to a prospective employer who has a more acute need for your skills and services.

Again: if I read your post correctly, you rejoined your firm two years ago, so your claiming that you "just" rejoined your company is a mischaracterization of your situation.

Comment: Good points to consider.  I realize others may consider 2 years as being closer to a typical stay in a job in today's age, while others consider it too short.  I suppose it depends upon a number of factors - what generation they entered the workforce, industry they work in, etc.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

---

Being a disabled professional makes it very hard for me to find a  new position.  As such, at times I envy people in your position, but I can empathize with your dilemma.

1. Re: The people who know you professionally realize your work ethic, so the trade off here is not whether you will sour relationships etc.  Ask Yourself:(See Re: 1)
2. There is a difference between "job hopping" and life in general.  For Example, you're spouses new job was a life move.  Now that you are both together you're both happier. Ask Yourself:(See Re: 2)

Re:1

> Does my current job, rehired or not, offer me the opportunities of Job
>   2?

If so, consider staying, and politely tell your manager you want to grow in those areas, and excel when given the opportunity.

Re: 2

> Is being a husband to my wife and living my life... being there as a
>   "family man" more important than my career?

If the answer is Yes, you will find that you can balance family and career throughout your career.  Sometimes, this will mean small resume quirks or moving for a spouse, or kids, or even a pay cut, etc.